# How to add a field name to a MsgBox in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

So essentially what im trying to do is add my Employees first name to a welcome message. Currently my code looks a bit like this:

```
    If txtPassword.Value = DLookup("EmplPassword", "Employees", "[EmplID]=" & cboEmployee.Value) Then
    MyEmplID = cboEmployee.Value
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin", acSaveNo
    If MyEmplID = 5 Then
        MsgBox "Welcome Admin"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Switchboard Main", acNormal
    Else
        MsgBox ("Welcome " & EmplFname.Text)
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Switchboard Main", acNormal
    End If
```

and this is the part im trying to make work:

```
MsgBox ("Welcome " & EmplFname.Text)
```

But I keep getting a "Run time error 424: Object Required" error.

*Note: This is for a school project, security in terms of the passwords are not part of the brief so Im not too worried about that*

Comment: Don't use Text property. Default in VBA is Value. What is EmplFname - field, variable? Where is its value coming from?

Comment: EmplFname is the name of the field which contains my employees first names. E.g. if the employee is David, I want the msgbox to say "Welcome David"

Comment: How do you expect to pull that value from table? Is the name available from a column of the combobox? If you close frmLogin form before running that code then that info is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the *employee name* in a column of the combobox, so this should do:

```
If Nz(txtPassword.Value) = Nz(DLookup("EmplPassword", "Employees", "[EmplID]=" & cboEmployee.Value)) Then
    MyEmplID = cboEmployee.Value
    EmplFname = cboEmployee.Column(n)   ' adjust n as needed.

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmLogin", acSaveNo

    If MyEmplID = 5 Then
        MsgBox "Welcome Admin"
    Else
        MsgBox "Welcome " & EmplFname
    End If
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Switchboard Main", acNormal
End If
```

Comment: That's my guess too. Note that `.Column()` is zero-based, so if it's the 2nd column, you need `.Column(1)`. @DylanEvans

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("EmplFname", "Employees", "[EmplID]=" & cboEmployee.Value)
```